# Which Java static code analyzer is recommendable for creating reports?

Tags: java, code-analysis, analyzer

I need a static code analyzer for Java that produces an output file about the: relationships of the classes (also inheritance relationships), fields of the classes,  method signatures, and method call hierarchies.

The important point is that the analysis data can be (easily) processed by a program. (I need the analysis for a kind of automatic "refactoring" tool for university.)

Comment: If you are going to refactor something, you'll need a tool that can parse Java and carry out name/type resolution anyway.  Such a tool should be able to produce the information you need more or less directly.  Why would you want a separate tool to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JastAdd](http://jastadd.org/) is a good source level analyzer (and much more).

You might prefer to work on bytecode level though. This is simpler, faster, provides all information you requested, works without source (obviously) and with other JVM-based languages. For that, either [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is a good choice.

**UPDATED**

Of course with bytecode you can't really perform source level refactoring (though you could do bytecode modification).

For completeness you may want to combine both approaches.